# Active Directory with ubuntu compputer

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, administration, active-directory, administrator

How I open Ubuntu device by a user from active directory after joining this device to the active directory ?

Comment: @Mann, when you say open the device do you mean using something like RDP or using some admin tool?

Comment: And additionally, you've tagget your question with WSL. Are you using WSL, or is it a physical machine?

Comment: It's  a virtual machine. Firstly I could join the ubuntu virtual machine to the domain controller of the active directory which install on ms server 2019. Now I want to give a user on Active directory the access to the ubuntu with Powers of the administrator (sudo)

Comment: How did you join it to the domain?

Comment: by following the same steps in this link : http://www.securityflux.com/?p=262